# Trackbar Percent to richtextbox Text

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a Trackbar and want it to add the Current Value to a richtextbox Text without replacing the whole Text Line

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Replace("aimbot_aimtime=85.000000", "aimbot_aimtime=" + trackbarpercent.Text + ".000000");
```

(i get the Value from my Label)

Thats what im using right now but it only Replaces it if the Text is "aimbot_aimtime=85.000000"

i want it to add the new Value after "aimbot_aimtime=NEWVALUE" but i cant get it to work atm

Comment: Are you creating an aimbot? lol

Comment: Why can't you replace the full string? richTextBox1.Rtf.Value = $"aimbot_aimtime={NEWVALUE}";

Comment: @Thumper i make a Config Editor. "richTextBox1.Rtf.Value = $"aimbot_aimtime={NEWVALUE}" is not working

Comment: Thumper, he would have to know the value that is in the control, which means tracking the old value in order to replace. Ralni, if you are making an editor why not a separate label and textbox as opposed to the richtextbox?

Comment: is it possible to track the the text without knowing the value behind it?
like find "aimbot_aimtime" and replace it with "aimbot_aimtime=435643"
@MarcLyon thats my design http://i.imgur.com/haCfPNM.png all working except the trackbars
 || 
maybe i got an idea.. the text is alway in the same line so maybe i should just replace the line instead of searching and replacing the text

Answer (score 0):

You have to know what the value is in order to replace it, which is why it only works when the value is your default value of 85.

In order to replace the text with the new text, you will have to track the previous value somewhere to use in your replacement. This means a field in your form, a property in some class. Let's say you create an int field on your form (myForm) called oldAimbot_aimtime. Every time the slider changes, put old value into this field. now your code becomes:

```
var prompt = "aimbot_aimtime=";
var oldvalue = string.Format("{0}{1}", prompt, myForm.oldAimbot_aimtime);
var newvalue = string.Format("{0}{1}", prompt, {NEWVALUE}.Format("#.######");
richTextBox1.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf.Replace(oldvalue, newvalue);
```

This code is off the top of my head and may not work exact, but it should replace the value. What is the value of using a richtextbox on a config screen? Can you post a screenshot?
OK,  I see the screenshot. Ethics aside (not sure there is such a thing as a legit aimbot). You are using the richtextbox presumably because it was the easiest control for you to style...

Where you use the richtextbox is probably better suited to a GridView, ListBox, maybe even a treeview where you have finer control over each element.

If you want to use the richtext, write code which emits each option, then you can obtain exact values to use in `rtf.Replace()`commands

Hope this helps.

Comment: got it working, but i
will keep this in mind for future projects thanks :)

Comment: So when you add an option which sorts alphabetically before aimbot_aimtime the "magic number" 7 will change...

Comment: its only an editor & all configs are the same except the values
so i dont have to worry about that Image= http://i.imgur.com/D2k2pbQ.png

Answer (score 0):

@Marc Lyon
I think a better way for me is to Replace the Line itself cause its always Line 7
Got it working, thanks to all who helped :)

```
    void changeLine(RichTextBox RTB, int line, string text)
    {
        int s1 = RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
        int s2 = line < RTB.Lines.Count() - 1 ?
                  RTB.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1) - 1 :
                  RTB.Text.Length;
        RTB.Select(s1, s2 - s1);
        RTB.SelectedText = text;
    }

    private void trackbarpercent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changeLine(richTextBox1, 7, "aimbot_aimtime=" + aimtimetrackbar.Value + ".000000");
    }
```